# Problem connecting to Ubuntu Server in same local network

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I have my LAN set up as below:

```
192.168.2.1: ADSL Router (DHCP Range: 192.168.2.2-192.168.2.250)
192.168.2.254: Wireless Access Point
192.168.2.253: Ubuntu Server (Static IP)
192.168.2.2: My Laptop (Connects to Internet via the Wireless AP)
```

NAT in router is active and set up to transfer requests made over port 80 to 192.168.2.253. Router's firewall is inactive. No IPs in DMZ.

My friends get Apache's It Works page when they try to enter http://my_external_ip. But I get Router's configuration page instead of that.

What should I check or do?

Thanks.

Comment: Dave is right. Your router sees the source address as being an internal IP and is routing you to the routers config page. If your friend can access the web server from the outside then it's working. You'll have to use your servers internal IP to see your website on the local network.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to access http://my_external_ip from within your network?

Remember that your ADSL router has two IP addresses, an internet IP address (my_external_ip) and an internal IP address (192.168.2.1), so when your HTTP request is generated by your laptop (102.168.2.2) it goes to the gateway (192.168.2.1) to be forwarded.  When the gateway receives the HTTP request it will notice that the destination IP address is the gateway system itself (since it has the IP address my_external_ip), so it will forward the HTTP request to port 80 on the ADSL router.

What you're expecting is that the HTTP request will be forwarded out through the internet interface and then somehow routed back to the ADSL router, which doesn't happen.

Dave

Answer (score 0):

Check your router documentation on how to change its administrative port. You can also access apache by your own IP, since you are on the same network as it. Sometimes home routers have problems doing NAT of a connection from inside the network back inside.